# Cakephp. How to give a path to display the image

Tags: php, html, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-2.0

Currently, I have given this path which is not working.

```
<img src=<?= @$this->Url->build("/images/categori/{$product->thumb}") ?> alt="" class="img-fluid" width="255" height="280">
```

However, I want to give the path is this way.

```
echo $this->Html->image
```

Comment: `not working` is so vague. Do you get any error or  ...?

Comment: @SamAmini . No It' displaying nothing. No images is shown in the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
<?= $this->Html->image(sprintf('/images/categori/%s', $product->thumb),
[
    'alt' => '',
    'class' => 'img-fluid', 
    'width' => 255, 
    'height' => 280
]); ?>
```

Read: https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/views/helpers/html.html#linking-to-images